How to run dotnet-svcutil with updated dependencies?
When I run dotnet-svcutil (latest, v2.1.0) for my .NET 8 project, I get several security warnings for out-of-date dependencies it's using. For example:
warning NU1903: Package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs' 6.0.1 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-555c-2p6r-68mm

I've done everything I can to specify that .NET 8 dependencies should be used, including:

Using dotnet SDK 8.0.202
The Directory.Build.props file in the solution of the project I'm running the tool in has <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework> specified.
My command has --targetFramework "net8.0" specified

How can I make sure the tool uses up-to-date dependencies?

Did you ever find an answer to this question?

@LinusProxy I haven't tried since then, but this GitHub issue seems to indicate that it's still happening.
